# What is the Windows XP VersionNT property value?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm building a [Condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/025bcetc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on one of my Registry entries in a Visual Studio Setup Project (`.vdproj`) and I want to install the key if, **and only if**, it's Windows XP it's being installed on. So, I found that I'll be able to use the `VersionNT` property in the condition [based off this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aak1cze8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

However, none of the linked articles, nor any of these Google searches really turned up anything for me:

- windows xp versionnt
- what is the windows xp versionnt

Would this condition be correct `VersionNT >= 600 && VersionNT < 700`? **NOTE:** I'm guessing at the `600` for Windows XP here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP is version 5.1.
(5.0 is 2000; 6.0 is Vista)

A full lists is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (search Google for `windows xp version number`)

Comment: Thanks a lot friend -I guess I need a couple more cups of coffee! Looks like `VersionNT=501` is going to be the right condition. What do you think? I got that from [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).